# How can I log errors occurring in an ASP.NET SOAP webservice before my methods are being executed?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

E.g. the message size of an incoming message is exceeding the message size limit from the web.config or a time out occurred.

Log calls in my web service method will not be executed because my method is not called yet.

I guess I need to somehow hook into the message processing of IIS.(!?)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525438(v=vs.90).aspx 

Maybe this will help?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET exceptions normally end up inside `Application_Error` event of `Global.asax.cs`, unless exception is swallowed inside the code.

If exception is outside of ASP.NET Pipeline, then you will need to view them in event viewer.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    }
}
```

*FYI: you might want to consider using logging framework like [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/).*